# Sonar : Fail to load plugin SonarPLSQL [plsql]

Tags: plsql, sonarqube, version, sonarqube-scan, sonarscanner

My SonarQube version is `sonarqube-7.5` community edition.

Sonar Scanner version is `sonar-scanner-3.3.0.1492-windows`

I downloaded `sonar-plsql-plugin-3.3.0.2273.jar` and placed it in `\sonarqube-7.5\extensions\plugins\` folder.

My operating system is Windows.

When I try to start SonarQube, I get the below exception in `web.log` file.

The PLSQL plugin which I am using is compatible with SonarQube 6.7+ and I am using version 7.5 (https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarPLSQL)

How could I resolve this issue and start the server?

```
2019.01.28 16:00:00 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2019.01.28 16:00:01 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Background initialization failed. Stopping SonarQube
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to load plugin SonarPLSQL [plsql]
    at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerExtensionInstaller.installExtensions(ServerExtensionInstaller.java:82)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel4.start(PlatformLevel4.java:586)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.start(Platform.java:211)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel34Containers(Platform.java:185)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.access$500(Platform.java:46)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$1.lambda$doRun$0(Platform.java:119)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$AutoStarterRunnable.runIfNotAborted(Platform.java:371)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$1.doRun(Platform.java:119)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$AutoStarterRunnable.run(Platform.java:355)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sonarsource/plugins/license/api/LicensedPluginRegistration
    at com.sonar.plsql.plugin.PlSqlPlugin.define(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerExtensionInstaller.installExtensions(ServerExtensionInstaller.java:72)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sonarsource.plugins.license.api.LicensedPluginRegistration
    at org.sonar.classloader.ParentFirstStrategy.loadClass(ParentFirstStrategy.java:39)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:87)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:76)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
2019.01.28 16:00:02 INFO  web[][o.s.p.StopWatcher] Stopping process
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sonar PLSQL plugin is a commercial product. You cannot install it on SonarQube Community edition. You have to buy at least Developer edition. Read more at [Plans & Pricing](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/).